# jquery, combining .not and .eq?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Yesterday I posted a problem with targeting 2 the same index within 2 separate unordered lists.

basically, items in unordered list #2 are hidden -- and when you click on an item in unordered list #1, an item with the same index in unordered list #2 will show up.

```
<ul class="list1">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list2">
  <li class="hide">item 1</li>
  <li class="hide">item 2</li>
  <li class="hide">item 3</li>
  <li class="hide">item 4</li>
</ul>

.hide { display: none; }
.active { display: block; }
```

The solution based on the responses is:

```
$('.list1').on('click', 'li', function() {    
    $('.list2 li').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
});
```

and this works great!

Now, I'm trying to make it so that when one line item shows up, the rest disappears.

I read that you can do this with the `.not()` method, but I'm struggling with binding it with the `.eq()` method.

if I have the two codes below on top of each other, it will only remove but not add.

```
$('.list2 li').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
$('.list2 li').not().eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
```

I figured I would have to put the `.eq()` inside the `.not()` method, but not sure how. Also I tried using if statements but that wasn't successful either..

would appreciate any input you can provide. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just remove the `active` on all `li` items and only add it to the relevant `li`?

```js
$('.list1').on('click', 'li', function() {    
  $('.list2 li')
    .removeClass('active')
    .eq($(this).index()).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
.active { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list1">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list2">
  <li class="hide">item 1</li>
  <li class="hide">item 2</li>
  <li class="hide">item 3</li>
  <li class="hide">item 4</li>
</ul>
```

If you really want to use the `not` function you can use it this way:

```js
$('.list1').on('click', 'li', function() {
  relevantLi = $('.list2 li').eq($(this).index())
  $('.list2 li').not(relevantLi).removeClass('active')
  relevantLi.addClass('active')
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
.active { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list1">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list2">
  <li class="hide">item 1</li>
  <li class="hide">item 2</li>
  <li class="hide">item 3</li>
  <li class="hide">item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: wow thank you. this is new... I wasn't aware you can combine both removeClass and toggleClass in the same line.. this is amazing..

Comment: The `removeClass` returns the exact same selector, so it actually return `$('.list2 li')`, therefore you can use it to continue apply other jquery functions on the result.

Comment: And you are welcome :) I also added a solution with the `not` as you asked (not sure why you would use it, but it's there for you to learn).